# About the exercises in Haims Brezis' book

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, book-recommendation

I am going through the Book of Haim Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev space and PDE, I find there a lot of interesting exercises, some of them are with useful hints some others with solution but the most of the difficult ones are without solutions, I would like to know if there is any boos or documents discussing those exercises? Also I will be so grateful if your recommend me any exercise books which are close to Brezis' ones especially about Sobolev space? Thanks in advance